# SQL Server Management Studio, Beginner

Tags: sql-server

So, I have this question: 
Use the following query to determine the principle_id values for suzie and jimmy.

```
 select *
 from sys.database_principals
 where name in ('suzie','jimmy')
```

Using the principle_id values obtained from the query above; write a SELECT query using the
sys.database_permissions table that lists ALL permissions that have been granted to suzie and jimmy.

Principal id's I got were "5 & 6"

Then I used:

```
SELECT*
FROM sys.database_permissions
WHERE grantee_principal_id in ('5','6')
```

Now the question is we're asked now to use the OBJECT_NAME function in your query to show the view names instead of just their
major_id values. I don't quite understand how to use the OBJECT_NAME function, I have been playing around and can't get it. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about the `mysql`-tag?

Comment: @Shnugo Opps that was an accident!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

`grator_principal_id` will return all objects where these principal **gave the grant** and `grantee_Prinicipal_id` return all objects where Suzie and Jimmy **were granted** [Details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx)

```
SELECT *
     ,OBJECT_NAME(major_id) AS TheObject
FROM sys.database_permissions
WHERE grantor_principal_id in (select principal_id
                               from sys.database_principals
                               where name in ('suzie','jimmy'))
```